# VB.NET Extension methods error

Tags: .net, vb.net, extension-methods

```
''' <summary> 
''' Transforms an item to a list of single element containing this item.
''' '</summary> 
<Extension()> _
Public Function ToList(Of T)(ByVal item As T) As List(Of T)
  Dim tList As New List(Of T)
  tList.Add(item)
  Return tList
End Function
```

usage

```
Dim buttonControl As New System.Windows.Forms.Button
Dim controls = buttonControl.ToList(Of System.Windows.Forms.Control)()
```

compile time error (on the last line)

> Extension method 'Public Function
>   ToList() As
>   System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)'
>   defined in '...Utils' is not generic
>   (or has no free type parameters) and
>   so cannot have type arguments.

Was is das?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ToList(Of TItem, TList As {New, List(Of TItem)})(ByVal item As TItem) As TList
  Dim tList As New TList
  tList.Add(item)
  Return tList
End Function
```

Basically your return type was a generic (declared as List (of T)). The function decaration here does it so that the return type is a list of the type that is being extended.

Comment: If I do just buttonControl.ToList() everything works well. But if I try to obtain a list of `Control`s from `Button` the error appears.

Comment: I see. What about just casting ButtonControl to a control before calling ToList (something like): (buttonControl as System.Windows.Forms.Control).ToList

Comment: with your example, the error changes:
`Type argument 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Windows.Forms.Button)'.`

Comment: very good remark )) Jon. That was simple and helped. (even is not an answer to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<Extension()>
    Public Function ToList(Of T)(ByVal Item As Object) As List(Of T)
        Dim tlist1 As New List(Of T)
        tlist1.Add(Item)
        Return tlist1
    End Function
```

Comment: this will use boxing and unboxing. not very optimal.